# xmpp for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmppframework

i tried to connect **XMPP Framework** with iPhone, it's working perfectly with **GMAIL** server.
but i can't connect with my own new chat server. It's not authenticating also?

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2):

check for the parameters

Hostname 
Port number 
user id
Password

- AIM: login.oscar.aol.com 5190
- Gadu-Gadu: appmsg.gadu-gadu.pl 80
- GTalk: talk.google.com 5222
- ICQ: login.oscar.aol.com 5190
- IRC: irc.freenode.net 7000
- MSN: messenger.hotmail.com 1863 (also 443 for initial connection)
- SIMPLE: localhost 5060 (of course there's a good chance you'll point it elsewhere)
- XMPP: jabber.org 5222
- Yahoo: scs.msg.yahoo.com 5050

Comment: where i want to change this? i can't able to find yar!

Comment: in app delegate there might be -(BOOL)connect method

Comment: [xmppStream setHostName:@"talk.google.com"];
[xmppStream setHostPort:5222];

Comment: Yes it's working fine, but i'm working with old XMPP Framework.. when i'm connecting updated XMPP framework, it's getting error __Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[XMPPStream supportsAuthenticationMechanism:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c731e0'__

Comment: Returns whether or not the given authentication mechanism name was specified in the
 * server's list of supported authentication mechanisms.

Comment: can you please let me know the host name and port number for yahoo and msn 

Appreciate your help.

Comment: AIM: login.oscar.aol.com 5190
Gadu-Gadu: appmsg.gadu-gadu.pl 80
GTalk: talk.google.com 5222
ICQ: login.oscar.aol.com 5190
IRC: irc.freenode.net 7000
MSN: messenger.hotmail.com 1863 (also 443 for initial connection)
SIMPLE: localhost 5060 (of course there's a good chance you'll point it elsewhere)
XMPP: jabber.org 5222
Yahoo: scs.msg.yahoo.com 5050

Comment: i added settings "MSN: messenger.hotmail.com 1863 (also 443 for initial connection)" for MSN but its not working. Please help me :(